# File comparison software for large amounts of drawing files

Tags: windows, comparison

I'm trying to find a program that will compare two directories full of these drawing and image files.

What this will be used for, is to update a full directory of drawings on a periodic basis. The directory will contain many folders, sub-folders, and sub-sub-folders and so on.

I want to be able to:

- Select individual files, or files that share similar names (E.g. "(Drawing1)#A.dwg" and "(Drawing1)#B.dwg")
- See file information (Last date modified, file size, etc.)
- Compare .dgn, .dwg, .tif and .pdf files (Not compare between files types - just two of the same type)
- Compare a list of files, not just two at a time.
- **OS:** Windows 7

**Some issues:**

There are going to some issues with the file comparisons, that should hopefully be able to be managed. Some of these issues are:

- Possible different file names (as mentioned above).
- The original copy of the directory may have been updated since the copy taken from off-site was taken - that is the copy may have been taken on Monday, and files were changed in the original after then, before the copy arrived on-site.
- Possible file-type differences. It's possible there may be occurences where a file, for whatever reason, might be a .dwg instead of a .dgn, or some other inconsistency.

If these cannot be managed, that's not essential. That can be managed manually, though it would be nice to have some indication of these inconsistencies.

---

I realise that some of these points may be a bit unclear, and if so, please ask for clarification, and I will do my best to explain.

Comment: Do you want to compare the content bitwise/binary, or by somehow interpreted content?

Comment: @Marcel, I basically want to know if the files are different in terms of content, i.e. if the drawing has been changed in any way (added a layer, moved a line etc). That will likely be different for the .tif and .pdf files though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Beyond compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) will do most of what you ask, with bonus - visual comparison & showing the differences! Please see http://www.scootersoftware.com/features.php?zz=screenshot&shot=PixCompare  I am having trouble linking to it for some reason :-(

> ```
> Select individual files, or files that share similar names (E.g. "(Drawing1)#A.dwg" and "(Drawing1)#B.dwg")
> ```

Yes, you can select any two files to compare

> ```
> See file information (Last date modified, file size, etc.)
> ```

Yes, plus image dimension in pixels and number of colours

> ```
> Compare .dgn, .dwg, .tif and .pdf files (Not compare between files types - just two of the same type)
> ```

I think that .dwg is very important for you and, alas, it cannot be compared graphically. However, if you only want to check if there is any difference, then do a hex compare.

TIFF is supported, [as is PDF](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_docxlspdf)

> ```
> Compare a list of files, not just two at a time.
> ```

Will compare two entire directory trees.

> ```
> OS: Windows 7
> ```

Yup

It's a great little program, well worth the money. Can even compare Excel files, windows registries, databases, etc.

[Download a demo](http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php) and give it a try.